# Using a recursive common table expression to find related tables in SQL Server using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am trying to write a recursive common table expression that creates a tree structure of all tables by foreign key, however I'm stuck with tables that have many to many relationships.. Can anyone solve this for me?

The first select is getting all the foreign keys. The second is linking them up with a parent/child join recursively. The recursion stops at table two even though there is a link to table three. Can anyone help? (added tables in the edit).

```
 CREATE TABLE [db].[table_one]
(
    [table_one_id] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, [one_column_one] int, [one_column_two] varchar(8), [one_column_three] varchar(7)
)

CREATE TABLE [db].[table_two]
(
    [table_two_id] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, [table_one_id] int, [table_three_id] int, [two_column_one] int, [two_column_two] varchar(8), [two_column_three] varchar(7)
)

CREATE TABLE [db].[table_three]
(
    [table_three_id] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, [table_four_id] int, [column_one] int, [column_two] varchar(8), [column_three] varchar(7)
)

CREATE TABLE [db].[table_four]
(
    [table_four_id] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, [column_one] int, [column_two] varchar(8), [column_three] varchar(7)
)

ALTER TABLE [db].[table_two] ADD CONSTRAINT [fk_table_one_table_two] FOREIGN KEY ([table_one_id]) REFERENCES [db].[table_one] ([table_one_id])
ALTER TABLE [db].[table_two] ADD CONSTRAINT [fk_table_three_table_two] FOREIGN KEY ([table_three_id]) REFERENCES [db].[table_three] ([table_three_id])
ALTER TABLE [db].[table_three] ADD CONSTRAINT [fk_table_four_table_three] FOREIGN KEY ([table_four_id]) REFERENCES [db].[table_four] ([table_four_id])

DECLARE @table_name as varchar(25) = 'table_one';
DECLARE @false as Bit = 0, @true as Bit = 1;

with relationship_tables as 
(
    select    s1.name as child_schema,        
             o1.Name as child_table,        
             s2.name as parent_schema,    
             o2.Name as parent_table    
    from sys.foreign_keys fk    
    inner join sys.objects o1 on fk.parent_object_id = o1.object_id    
    inner join sys.schemas s1 on o1.schema_id = s1.schema_id    
    inner join sys.objects o2 on fk.referenced_object_id = o2.object_id    
    inner join sys.schemas s2 on o2.schema_id = s2.schema_id    
    where not (s1.name = s2.name and o1.name = o2.name) /*exclude self-referencing*/
)
,
hierarchy AS 
(        
       SELECT rt.parent_schema, 
              rt.parent_table, 
              s.name as child_schema,
              t.name as child_table, 
              CONVERT(VARCHAR(4096), '>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), t.name ) + '>' ) as path, 
              @false as Loop, 0 AS Level
        FROM    (select * from sys.tables where name <> 'sysdiagrams') t    
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id    
        LEFT OUTER JOIN relationship_tables rt ON s.name = rt.child_schema AND t.name = rt.child_schema    
        WHERE rt.parent_schema IS NULL
       AND t.name LIKE '%' + @table_name + '%'
        UNION    ALL
       SELECT  rt.parent_schema, 
              rt.parent_table, 
              rt.child_schema,
              rt.child_table,
              CONVERT(VARCHAR(4096), path + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), rt.child_table ) + '>' ), 
              CASE WHEN CHARINDEX( '>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), rt.child_table ) + '>', PATH) = 0 THEN @false ELSE @true END, 
              hr.Level + 1
        FROM    relationship_tables rt   
        INNER JOIN hierarchy hr ON rt.parent_schema = hr.child_schema AND rt.parent_table = hr.child_table
       WHERE hr.Loop = 0 
)
select parent_table, child_table, path, level from hierarchy
order by level
```

Here is another attempt that isn't working:

```
declare @Objects_In_Objects table
(
  ObjectID varchar(25), 
  ParentObjectId varchar(25)
)

declare @Objects table
(
  ObjectId varchar(25), 
  Name varchar(50)
)

insert into @Objects values
('db.table_one', 'Start table'),  
('db.table_two', 'Many to Many'),  
('db.table_three', 'Related Table'),  
('db.table_four', 'Related Table')

--ObjectID--ParentObjectId
insert into @Objects_In_Objects values
('db.table_one', 'db.table_two'),
('db.table_three', 'db.table_two'),
('db.table_four', 'db.table_three')

DECLARE @ObjectId varchar(25)
SET @ObjectId = 'db.table_one';

;WITH Tree AS
(
   SELECT A.ObjectID, A.Name, o.ParentObjectID, 1 AS 'Level'
   FROM @Objects A
   INNER JOIN @Objects_In_Objects o ON A.ObjectID = o.ParentObjectID OR A.ObjectId = o.ObjectID
   WHERE A.ObjectId = @ObjectId          -- use the A.ObjectId here

   UNION ALL

   SELECT A2.ObjectID, A2.Name, B.ParentObjectID, t.Level + 1 AS 'Level'
   FROM Tree t 
   INNER JOIN @Objects_In_Objects B ON B.ParentObjectID = t.ObjectID
   INNER JOIN @Objects A2 ON A2.ObjectId = B.ObjectId        
)
SELECT *
FROM Tree
INNER JOIN @Objects ar on tree.ObjectId = ar.ObjectId
```

Comment: Completely unclearly what the domain you work in, what task you try to done

Comment: What's wrong with the results you are getting?

Comment: When the child table has no primary key link, such as a many to many table, the recursion stops.